# How to create a global variable that can be accessed from external javascript as well as asp.net website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my website we have one common javascript where we will assign value to a variable i want to call that variable in my aspx page as well as in another javascript file can anyone let me know how to declare that kind of varibale globally .

Answer (score 0):

you can write a common javascript file which will contain all the global variable(assuming they are constant and they wont change).

if you have the variable value as non constant, there is noway that you can put it in a javascript file, instead you can use the local storage, cookies to store the information and use it across your javascript files.

the life time of a javascript variable is limited to the page, you navigate to other page its lost.

Comment: Thanks Chandra for your reply in my case it is non constant according to the gridview rowdatabound i am planning to assign the value to the variable which i will be using in another aspx page in another function previously we were using cookies but due to some issues we are planing to change the logic ,please let me know if possible to use any other logic

Comment: if you gotto do it on the client side then the storage should also be on the client side, if not cookies you can access LocalStorage and store your objects there (as a string) , else you can store on the server and access it via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not expect any page to assign new values in your common javascript, you can add it to the page as the first header script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/common.js"></script>
```

If you want to assign new values and reuse them, it is possible if you let ASP.Net generate your javascript file by passing a query string to the next page's URL, then in that page's script tag. Let's assume that your common variable is called "myGlobalVar". Supposing that "common_js.aspx" dynamically generates your variable definition, you can have something like this :

(URL : www.mysite.com/products.aspx?myGlobalVar=3)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/common_js.aspx?myGlobalVar=3"></script>
```

This will keep track of your new js value whenever an update has to be made.

But if so, you may likely want to use a cleaner way to achieve what you want, for example : using the context manager instead of common js vars.